# How to use php and html together to edit header of a webpage

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following commands from a wordpress theme.

```
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>


<header id="masthead" class="site-header <?php echo ( get_theme_mod( 'panoramic-header-layout', 'panoramic-header-layout-standard' ) == 'panoramic-header-layout-centered' ) ? sanitize_html_class( 'panoramic-header-layout-centered' ) : sanitize_html_class( 'panoramic-header-layout-standard' ); ?>" role="banner">



<?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'panoramic-header-layout', 'panoramic-header-layout-standard' ) == 'panoramic-header-layout-centered' ) : ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'library/template-parts/header', 'centered' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'library/template-parts/header', 'centered' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Now I need to add two logos one is on the left and the other one is on the right.

How to do that?

Comment: you have to read theme documentation.

Comment: Just add the two logos directly in the HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section, simply add the icons to the HTML section and remove the theme-specific images. Here's a sample showing how this could be done:

HTML part:

```
<header>
  <img class="logo left" src="PATH_TO_LEFT_LOGO.png">
  <div class="header-text left">
    This may be a title.
  </div>
  <img class="logo right" src="PATH_TO_RIGHT_LOGO.png">
  <br class="header-clear" />
</header>
```

CSS to align the logo files:

```
.header-text {
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.header-text.left,
.logo.left{
  float: left;
}
.logo.right {
  float: right;
}
.header-clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

If you don't need the header text, remove the DIV layer and the appropriate rules from the CSS section. It should also be obvious that you will have to replace the paths to the logo images matching your configuration :-)

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/qwx3jdvv/2/) showing the above code.